# Random Forests - Regression or Classification?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, random-forest

I have a question relating to use of Random Forests:

My dataset's output are integers (0 to 19), and is unbalanced. The histogram below shows the distribution of the data.

I am open to using either Random Forests regression or classification, however, I am uncertain how to evaluate the results.
Regression produces continuous predictions - how can I compare them to the discrete true values?
And given the 19 classes, is it wise to use classification instead of regression?

I'd really appreciate any help or advice.

[image: Histogram showing distribution]

Answer (score 2):

First, are the classes ordinal? If they're not and you run regression, you'll be making misleading assumptions about adjacency.

Second, if they are ordinal, are they a discretization of a continuous variable? Are the bins equidistant? If not, then regression in the transformed scale would lead to odd results. For example, say that bin 1 goes from 1 to 100 and bin 2 goes from 101 to 110. How do you interpret a RF prediction of 1.7?  If this is the case, you might be best-off imputing with the mean of the bin in the original scale.

If the results are ordinal and the bins are equidistant, I'd just run regression. Assuming that the rounding factor is uncorrelated with any of your predictors, the only consequence is a bit of noise.